# Is it possible set minTime on Angularjs bootstrap timepicker directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker

We had been using jquery ui for datepicker and timepicker for some time now. We recently started using angularjs, it allows for two way binding and it has reduced lot of code. I use the ang. bootstrap timepicker directive, it works fine. But is there any way to set minTime and maxTime attribute where timepicker allows user to pick time after 9 am and below 5pm.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpfull:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425976/how-to-set-min-time-and-max-time-for-angular-timepicker][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425976/how-to-set-min-time-and-max-time-for-angular-timepicker

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in the latest angular bootstrap - min & max attributes